# dynamically add CSS class on a div tag with other than id and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which contains an anchor tag as below.

```
<div id="sideTabs">
        <a href="#" type="click" >
            Click Here
        </a>
</div>
```

For some reasons I cannot set id or class on anchor tag and there is a attribute `type` in the anchor tag.

I have a CSS class

```
.selected {
            background: rgb(41, 41, 59);
            color: #fff;
}
```

I want to add this class dynamically when I click on anchor tag.
I know how to add a CSS class with reference to `id` and `class`.

```
$(#"id of anchortag").attr("class", selected);
```

As I do not have id attribute can some one explain me how to add a CSS class with some other attribute, in my case `type`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this selector `a[type="click"]` to get that/those element(s) and use the function `addClass` to add a new class to that/those element(s).

```
$('a[type="click"]').addClass('selected')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$("a[type='click']")` to set click listener on...

```js
$("a[type='click']").on("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected");
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background: rgb(41, 41, 59);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sideTabs">
  <a href="#" type="click">
            Click Here
        </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the selector and the arguments to `attr` in quotes because they're strings

```
$("#id of anchortag").attr("class", "selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

You add class by using `.addClass('selected');`

so `$('#id-you-have').addClass('selected');`

But keep in mind that your `a` tag doesn't have an ID